# Is there a way to keep my Internal ports the same when I restart my internet?

Tags: ip, router

I host many video game servers, and have many ports forwarded. However, from time to time, I have to restart my router, and every time I do that, my computer's Internal IP is changed. This means that I have to edit all of my forwarded ports, and make them apply to my computer/Internal IP. While this is easy, it takes awhile to do.

My question is: How can I give my computer one single Internal IP that will stay the same even if my router/internet restarts, and other devices (Tablets, smartphones, etc) are connecting and disconnecting constantly?

Comment: Or alternatively, assign a static ip address to your server.

Comment: @joeqwerty How would one accomplish that? You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the router, the name varies, but something along the line of "Address Reservation", in LAN IP Setup.

When you specify a reserved IP address for a PC on the LAN, that PC will always receive the same IP address each time it accesses the DHCP server.

You then can give the MAC address of the device to fix, and assign a permanent IP address for it.

Comment: You could also simply use static IPs on your internal network.